# Strange modules loads on debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have ASP.Net Core 2 project.
When I run debug in output windows displayed strange strings:

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'gnwgve2t.4un'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'wjnpx45y.xq5'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'gwrcii3n.1h4'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

And in modules window these items displayed as loaded.
[image]

Dependencies do not contain anything suspicious.

[image]

What is it? How delete this?

Comment: Those are dynamically generated assemblies. Which code generated them exactly is hard to tell with given information